# Is there a (CSS) filter to cut out the outlines of an image on top of another image?

Tags: css, image, filter

I've got two images on top of my webpages. One is a rectangle-shaped JPG file banner, the other is a wave-shaped SVG vector file. Similar to how Adobe Illustrator has its pathfinder tool to cutout shapes: Is there any way to invert-cutout the wave from the banner, using any sort of CSS filter or blend mode or something?

The reason I want to do this using CSS is because it would only require me to change one HTML template for the banner. Otherwise I would have to edit 125+ unique banner image files. Editing the wave file is not a problem if needed, as I would only need it once for the banner template.

**Example banner:**

[image]

**Example wave:**

[image]

**Desired result:**
(the banner should look like this)

[image]

Comment: Check [`mask-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-image)

Comment: Ahh, I knew something like this existed somewhere. Many thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you can use `clip-path` 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path